# Origin of $E$ in $E^\infty$-object

Tags: reference-request, algebraic-topology, category-theory, terminology

I post the question here because it is not really a research-level question. I can't find the answer in the [nLab](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/HomePage). Morally speaking, an $E^\infty$-object means an $A^\infty$-object (associative up to coherent higher homotopies) which is commutative up to coherent higher homotopies.

> Where does the 'E' come from ?

Comment: I believe that the $E$ stands for *E*verything since such an object is supposed to have an associative, commutative, unital, etc product.

Comment: ^This is also my recollection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indeed, the "E" stands for *E*verthing. The term was originally coined by Boardman and Vogt in their paper "Homotopy-Everything H-Spaces", which is available here https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.bams/1183530111.